# What is the easiest way to see the MySQL queries run by a CiviCRM page?

Tags: debugging, mysql

When debugging CiviCRM pages, is there a native way to emit the SQL statements being run, eg on a Search page? I'm looking for something easier than finding the code for the page and putting in a debug_var kind of statement. I'd prefer to not have to rely on a Drupal module like cTools, since we work with other CMSes frequently these days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to see *everything*, you can enable MySQL logging as follows (don't do this on production!):

1. From the mysql console (or within an application like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)), run:

   ```
   SET global general_log = 1;
   SET global log_output = 'table';
   ```
2. Look at all queries run within the last 15 seconds

   ```
   select * 
   from mysql.general_log 
   where 
     command_type = 'Query' and 
     event_time > now() - interval 15 second;
   ```
3. Try to find queries on the civicrm_contact table

   ```
   select * from mysql.general_log 
   where 
     argument like '%civicrm_contact%' and 
     argument not like '%general_log%' 
   order by event_time desc;
   ```
4. Clear the log

   ```
   truncate table mysql.general_log;
   ```
5. Turn off logging

   ```
   SET global general_log = 0;
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Try setting:

define('CIVICRM_DAO_DEBUG', 1);

in your civicrm.settings.php file, this might work based on a quick glance at the code.

The output will appear onscreen and in the CiviCRM log file (eg `sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM*log` or `media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM*log` or `wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM*log`)

Answer (score 3):

If your page happens to be a report, you can install the [Extended Reports](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extended+Reports+Extension) extension which will display the full sql query being run.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure wether such a functionality exist in CiviCRM but something wich might be worth a look at is the logfiles